# JSON или БД. Что для чего нужно?

Tags: javascript, база-данных, json, node.js

Не могу понять как работать с данными.
У меня есть большой JSON содержащий информацию по товарам.

Возможно ли как то частями его выгружать, допустим по 20 товаров для одной страницы? Или для этого уже нужна база данных?

Не могу понять преимуществ и недостатков того или иного способа.

Прошу просто и понятно разъяснить

Comment: @nörbörnën, а можно об этом где то подробнее почитать?

Comment: Зависит от того, насколько большой JSON. Если он продолжает расти, то однажды наступит такой момент, что загружаться он станет непозволительно долго (десятки секунд и больше), а впоследствии и такой, что он просто перестанет помещаться в оперативную память и работать перестанет вообще всё. Это не обязательно значит, что нужно использовать именно БД, но как минимум может намекать на возможную необходимость переработки структуры хранения. Если же json умещается в районе нескольких мегабайт, то, возможно, БД не даст никакой значимой выгоды

Comment: в документации [fs.createReadStream](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options) написано о возможности указания начальной и конечной позиции при потоковом чтении файла

Comment: @nörbörnën насколько я понимаю, в общем случае это не очень применимо, так как формат json не предоставляет вспомогательной информации, позволяющей выбрать эти самые начальную и конечную позицию

Comment: @andreymal согласен. однако для полноты информации этот способ должен был быть предложен

Comment: Мне интересно как вы этот json редактируете или даже просто дописываете к нему что нибудь. ведь малейшая правка с изменением длины данных заставит переписать весь файл (что бы сдвинуть то, что после точки вставки). А что бы дописать в конец файла, надо аккуратно отрезать от конца файла нужное кол-во закрывающихся скобок как минимум, потом вписать блок и вернуть скобки на место. В общем развлечение еще то.

Comment: А если у вас node.js, он же все время в памяти, файл один раз подгрузили и работайте себе с ним уже разобранным, если конечно ОЗУ позволяет. А если не позволяет, вам на его разбор постоянный все равно никаких ресурсов не хватит